# How can I use data annotation validations in wcf rest service data contracts

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I am using WCF rest service in my application. Just need to confirm whether I can use data annotations validations in data contracts like I use in MVC models. If yes how can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data annotations was not designed for WCF use:

> The System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations namespace provides attribute
>   classes that are used to define metadata for **ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET**
>   data controls.

From MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx

There is some alternatives to do the same in WCF, like this:
https://wcfdataannotations.codeplex.com/

And this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647875.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ricardo